# eBay API not getting the complete details of the product on the basis of findItemsByCategoryRequest search

Tags: php, ebay-api

While fetching the cars data from ebay using ebay API not getting the Item specifics data from ebay such as Model, Year, Variant etc.

Below is the code used by me for fetching the data using ebay API:-

```
$xmlrequest  = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n";
$xmlrequest .= "<findItemsByCategoryRequest xmlns=\"http://www.ebay.com/marketplace/search/v1/services\">\n";
$xmlrequest .= "<categoryId>9801</categoryId>";
<entriesPerPage>10</entriesPerPage>\n</paginationInput>\n";
$xmlrequest .= "</findItemsByCategoryRequest>";

// Set up the HTTP headers
$headers = array(
'X-EBAY-SOA-OPERATION-NAME: findItemsByCategory',
'X-EBAY-SOA-SERVICE-VERSION: 1.3.0',
'X-EBAY-SOA-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT: XML',
'X-EBAY-SOA-GLOBAL-ID: EBAY-GB',
'X-EBAY-SOA-SECURITY-APPNAME: APP-ID',
'Content-Type: text/xml;charset=utf-8',
);
```

> [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
>                           (

```
                        [itemId] => 273628851708
                        [title] => Volkswagen Passat Estate 2.0tdi Sport 
                        [globalId] => EBAY-GB
                        [primaryCategory] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                            (
                                [categoryId] => 9873
                                [categoryName] => Volkswagen
                            )

                        [galleryURL] => http://thumbs1.ebaystatic.com/m/mrCuCMB_TFLzjLd25prOS2w/140.jpg
                        [viewItemURL] => http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Volkswagen-Passat-Estate-2-0tdi-Sport-/273628851708
                        [paymentMethod] => MOCC
                        [autoPay] => false
                        [postalCode] => DY84GG
                        [location] => Stourbridge,United Kingdom
                        [country] => GB
                        [shippingInfo] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                            (
                                [shippingServiceCost] => 0.0
                                [shippingType] => FreePickup
                                [shipToLocations] => Worldwide
                            )

                        [sellingStatus] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                            (
                                [currentPrice] => 1395.0
                                [convertedCurrentPrice] => 1395.0
                                [sellingState] => Active
                                [timeLeft] => P2DT14H29M9S
                            )

                        [listingInfo] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                            (
                                [bestOfferEnabled] => true
                                [buyItNowAvailable] => false
                                [startTime] => 2018-12-27T22:49:09.000Z
                                [endTime] => 2018-12-30T22:48:09.000Z
                                [listingType] => FixedPrice
                                [gift] => false
                                [watchCount] => 4
                            )

                        [condition] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                            (
                                [conditionId] => 3000
                                [conditionDisplayName] => Used
                            )

                        [isMultiVariationListing] => false
                        [topRatedListing] => false
                    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Ebay has a lot of different APIs. It looks like you're using the Finding API which doesn't seem to have this functionality. You should be able to use [GetMultipleItems](https://developer.ebay.com/devzone/shopping/docs/CallRef/GetMultipleItems.html) in the shopping API if you want item specifics for a list of items. Pass `ItemSpecifics` into `IncludeSelector`.